# Android Design: When should one load data (from a DB/or web service)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, asynchronous

I'm currently designing an android app which will incorporate a contacts (friends) feature. This process is going to be tied to fetching from a database and getting pictures off the web.

I was just wondering what is the best/most used model to do this in android. Should all contacts be loaded from DB and then into the listview on the start of the app / should the data from DB be loaded at the start of the app and then the list view populated when one clicks the contacts buttons.

I'm still fairly new to android so if you guys have any tips it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to populate your listview once you get to the activity that displays it, [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) is a good place to execute your task.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid lifecycle problems you should take a look at loaders :

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Answer (score 0):

Loading data on app start depends on what you show on your Main activity. If you're going to show list of contacts on app start then you should load data in your Main activity's [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) event.

You should be loading data when you actually need it only. So, when you're planning to add button which should show contact data then you should defer loading till button click event.

From programming point of view, you should use [Loader Pattern](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) to achieve smooth user experience.

Below articles might help.

1. [Local Databases with SQLiteOpenHelper by Codepath](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper)
2. [Understanding LoaderManager](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html)
3. [Nice notes on CursorAdapter](https://shortnotesandroid.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/cursoradapter/)
4. [Running a query with CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html)